# Using Moq to create a mock the type with constructor

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm just getting started on unit testing on a simple method and I'm stuck on the below line (specifically the web service object):

```
public string GetToken()
{
    WebService ws = new WebService("https://example.com/", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Config/agent.txt"));

    Token token = ws.GetToken(name, values, stuff);
}
```

At first I tried to use an interface to mock the HttpContext call, but I had trouble going that route, so I'm wondering if I can just Mock the web service? Something like below, but then I don't know how to actually 'inject' this Mock object into the getToken method/class.

```
var webServiceMock = new Mock<WebService>("http://test.example.com", "/test/file/path");
//maybe something along this syntax?
webServiceMock.Setup(it => it.CreateGetMethod(uri)).Returns(mockWebService.Object);
```

I am working through your interface solution and I can't figure out how to setup the implementation for the token without a WebService.  It calls GetIssuedTokenType but that doesn't exist in WebServiceImpl

```
    public class TokenImpl : IToken
    {
        public Token getToken(WebService ws)
        {
             Token token = ws.GetIssuedTokenType(
                  "http://example.com",
                  "john.doe@example.com", values,
                  WebService.TokenType.EX20);

        return samlToken;
        }
     }

    public class WebServiceImpl : IWebService
    {

        public WebService getWebService()
        {
            WebService ws = new WebService("https://example.com", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Config/agent.txt"));
        return ws;
    }
}
```

A larger snippet of the class for reference:

```
WebService ws = new WebService("https://example.com", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Config/agent.txt"));
ws.BasicAuthUsername = "username";
ws.BasicAuthPassword = "pass1234";

SecurityToken token = ws.GetIssuedTokenType(audience, nameId, values, type);
```

Comment: Moq mocks methods and properties of an interface. Only concrete implementation of an interface has a constructor. So create an interface which you service will implement and mock it up.

Comment: So if I want to Mock these objects, each one needs an interface with a test and non-test implementation?  And all of these need to be added as constructor arguments for the class itself?

Comment: You can have an interface and implement it in various ways, say real implementation and test/stub implementation. Or instead the later one - just mock this interface up.

Comment: Is it alright to add fields to the interface if their are subsequent calls to the ws for getting and setting?

Comment: Please elaborate. Interface is a contract, it usually has only method, less often properties too. It sounds like you want to create a stub implementation: you pass something to its ctor, make a call, it will return what you've passed. It's one of the options. Another one would be  using Setup() and Return() from Moq.

Comment: So I'll be using the implementation in place of web service itself now, if there is a method that wants to set the web service username (for example), the implementation has no knowledge of that field right?  I'd have to add something to the implementation to store that variable or would I still be stubbing with one of the techniques you mentioned above?

Comment: Can you show please some code? How you'd like it to be implemented (maybe some pseudo-code with comments) or how it's implemented now and where it lacks something you'd like.

Comment: Side note: moq can handle virtual methods too, but generally proxies created by VS for web services do not have interfaces nor virtual methods :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface ITokenProvider
{
    string GetToken();
}

public class WebTokenProvider
{
    public string GetToken
    {
        // your actual implementation
    }
}
```

Mock in tests:

```
var mock = new Mock<ITokenProvider>();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetToken()).Returns("test-token-1");
```